# Import Excel into SAP Business One

Tags: excel, sapb1

Is there any way to import Excel data or file into SAP Business One, especially into version 9.2? I did some research and found some options, which are:

1) copy paste
2) import from excel (inside the Administration -->Data import/export)
3) DTW

Is there another easier option apart from these?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to import multiple Documents, or Linked Documents, or Documents with Rows, Data Transfer Workbench is great.

If you just need to copy a lot of rows from a spreadsheet to a grid, copy-paste is adequate.

There's also the SAP Business One Integration Framework (B1IF), though that has a pretty steep learning curve from what I've seen, and it involves a lot of XML.

If you're feeling adventurous, you can also roll your own using the SAP DI .Net SDK

Comment: Thank you Zac. I ususally use DTW to do this. But, there is a an important requirement that require me to use Import from Excel only to import the data. Thank you for your info Zac

Comment: That's something that I've never had reason to use, so I can't really comment on it, sorry.